# Docker: sync files created by dockerfile with host through volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

When i use docker-compose with volumes to sync my files from host to container i cant see any new files created in the dockerfile

my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"

services:
  web:
    image: nginx:latest
    volumes:
        - ./:/code
    links:
        - php

  php:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./:/code
```

My dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM php:7-fpm

WORKDIR /code

RUN touch testfile
```

Of course thats a simplified example, but why do I not see the "testfile" on my host System? if I use `docker-compose exec php touch testfile` everything works as expected, i see the testfile on my host.
From my understanding I do need to see it outside of my container for it to be shared with the other containers with the same volume (in this example nginx)

Comment: If you downvote my question, please explain to me what i did wrong. Downvoting without explanation wont help me for future questions..

Comment: I didn't downvote but the likelyhood is the person thought that you didn't do enough research on how Docker works. But this is a place to ask questions and learn.

Answer (score 1):

When you run `RUN touch testfile` within your `Dockerfile` it creates the `testfile` within the image itself.

Now when you start your container and volume mount your `./` directory to `/code`, it will mount over your existing `/code` folder in the image which is why you see it empty. If you didn't add the volume mount in your compose file, it would have the `testfile` in there.

Note: I don't fully understand your use case but if you wanted your image to create that file within the volume mount, you would need to add it to your entrypoint.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. My usecase is that i have an example config file (example.config.php) and want to rename it to config.php. Now i still would want my directory to mount in the container, because i want to set it up for development purposes, so sadly COPY . . and then a RUN mv example... config.. wouldn't be possible

Comment: Also, i tried doing that in the entrypoint or CMD in my dockerfile which works, but lets my container exit right after. I understand why it exits, because the container did its job, but appending a `&& tail -f /dev/null` doesnt work either, as advised by many other related questions

Comment: After trying for hours i ended up with a third service that just tests if the file exists and copies it if it doesnt. Like an "init service" that executes a bash script as entrypoint. Doesnt sound like an ideal solution to me tho, do you have a better one?